# Copy from text to text in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I am new to the community and this is my first question, I hope I am doing it correctly.

My question: 
I am learning some networking and analysis and have a very long list of MAC addresses that I want to put in the same sentence using the command line but I do not know how.

Example: MAC addresses:

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz
```

The output I need:

```
The mac address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx is not found - but...
The mac address yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy is not found - but...
The mac address zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz is not found - but...
```

How can I achieve this?

I hope you have the time to help and excuse my ignorance, I am still learning and wouldn't ask if I didn't spend some time searching. I saw people using sed, awk, and perl but I understood nothing sense the whole linux world is new for me. Please provide me with some explanation with the commands so I learn how to do it myself for the next time.

Comment: One question per post please

Comment: @Zanna Thank you very much. I just edited the question and here is my second question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/861690/copy-specific-text-from-a-multiple-line-file-and-paste-it-in-another-file-automa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your list is in a file called `file` with nothing else in it (as appears to be the case), you could use:

```
sed 's/.*/The mac address & is not found - but.../' file
```

- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*` match any number of any characters on each line
- `&` print what was matched earlier here

If you see the output you want, repeat the command (hit the up arrow to see and edit the previous command) adding redirection (`>`) to a new file at the end like this:

```
sed 's/.*/The mac address & is not found - but.../' file > newfile
```

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to first question:**

```
sed 's/$/ is not found - but.../' FILENAME | sed 's/^/The mac address /'
```

This usage of `sed` just replaces fist string with the second one. `$` means end of the line. `^` means beginning of the line.

**Answer to second question:**

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' FILENAME | sed 's/IP address:/This computer ip address is/' | sed 's/Computer name:/and is under the name/'
```

First `sed` merge every two lines. Remain `sed`s replace old expression with new expression to build your new line.